# clang++ 15.0.7 incompatible with stdlib from gcc 13.2.1?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am using a version of Fedora 38 that gives this error when compiling with clang.
I know it has to do with clang using the GNU standard library but I wonder if there is a new incompatibility here.

I can see this issue was popular many years ago, but I couldn't find a workaround.

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 15.0.7 (Fedora 15.0.7-4.fc38)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ CXX=clang++ cmake ..

$ make
cd /home/user/boost-multi/.build.clang++/test && /usr/bin/clang++ allocator.cpp
In file included from /home/user/boost-multi/test/allocator.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/test/test_tools.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:48:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/stdlib/libstdcpp3.hpp:78:
/usr/include/unistd.h:226:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include <stddef.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

UPDATE: Compiling a simple hello world works well with clang++, but as soon as I `#include<boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` I can't compile. This happens with `boost-1.78.0-11.fc38`.

UPDATE 2: As another data point, I have another docker image of Fedora 38 and it works with `g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)` and `clang version 16.0.6 (Fedora 16.0.6-2.fc38)` and `boost-1.78.0-11.fc38`.

Comment: Have you installed llvm?

Comment: @273K, good point, I assumed it would be installed with `clang`. But, yes, it is installed: `Package llvm-15.0.7-2.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.` or where you referring to another component of llvm?

Comment: No, that should work. Perhaps Makefile is not working. Try to compile a hello world program with clang++ in a terminal.

Comment: Hello world works but not once I include the boost header. Clang 16 (from another docker image) works too. (see my updates)

Comment: You might try `#include <unistd.h>` in your hello world program.

Comment: @273K, yes, same problem, it is not a Boost problem in this sense. However, I don't know if one is supposed to include this header directly,

Comment: The same happens when including the proper C++ header, `#include <cstddef>`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the clang package, it's not configured to look in the correct directories for headers. You could try adding the correct paths in the command line or you might have to just build clang from source